# v-expansion-panels with nested panels in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm unable to make an expansion panel with items that have sub items and there is a sub item that has Childs. I am trying to make expansion panels look like that in
[vuetify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTfPK.png) but I unable to do so. I tried this code but it didn't work as needed.

### Code

```
    <template>
<div class="scroll-inside">
            <div id="accordian" class="accordian">
              <v-expansion-panels
                v-model="panel"
                accordion
                hover
                focusable
                flat
              >
                <v-expansion-panel v-for="(item, i) in rightMenu" :key="i">
                  <v-expansion-panel-header
                  
                  >
                    <div class="icon" :class="item.icon"></div>
                    <span style="line-height: 1.3em">{{ item.text }}</span>
                  </v-expansion-panel-header>
                  <v-expansion-panel-content>
                    <div
                      class="right_child_menu"
                      v-for="(child, i) in item.child"
                      :key="i"
                    >
                      <div>
                        <router-link :to="child.to" exact>
                          <i class="ico-squares right_child_menu_icon"></i>
                          <div class="right_child_menu_text">
                            {{ child.name }}
                          </div>
                        </router-link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </v-expansion-panel-content>
                </v-expansion-panel>
              </v-expansion-panels>
            </div>
          </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
  name: 'App',
  watch: {
    
    },
  mounted() {
    
  },
  computed: {
    rightMenu: function () {
      let menu = []
      menu.push({
        icon: 'ico-dp-production-card',
        text: 'Programming',
        child: [
          {
            {
              text: 'Java',
              subchilds: [
                {
                    name: 'Spring Boot',
                    to: { name: 'SpringBootComponent' },
                },
               {
                    name: 'Spring Data Jpa',
                    to: { name: 'SpringDataComponent' },
                },
                ...
              ],
             
            },
            {
              name: 'Others',
              to: { name: 'OthersComponent' },
            }
          },
        ],
      }),
       menu.push({
        icon: 'ico-dp-production-card',
        text: 'Database',
        child: [
          {
            name: 'Oracle',
            to: { name: 'OracleComponent' },
          },
          ...
        ],
      })
      return menu
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rightMenu: [],
      isFullScreen: false,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

I expect to make a side menu like
[the following screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y180.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A v-list-group is the component for your purpose:

```
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" width="300">
    <v-list>
      <v-list-group value="Programming Group">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-list-item
            v-bind="props"
            prepend-icon="mdi-code-braces"
            title="Programming"
          ></v-list-item>
        </template>
        <v-list-group value="Java Group">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Java"></v-list-item>
          </template>
          <v-list-item title="Spring Data"></v-list-item>
          <v-list-item title="Spring Security"></v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
        <v-list-group value="Others Group">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Others"></v-list-item>
            <!-- Others -->
          </template>
          <v-list-item title="Other Stuff"></v-list-item>
        </v-list-group>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
    <v-list>
      <v-list-group value="Database Group" prepend-icon="mdi-database">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
          <v-list-item v-bind="props" title="Database"></v-list-item>
        </template>
        <v-list-item title="Oracle"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item title="SQL Server"></v-list-item>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

you can also use v-for and add click handlers depending on your needs:

have look here: [vuetify docs sub-group component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#sub-group)

[playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)